# how to change a page headline in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i searched a lot but i couldn't find how to change my page headline title, i'm not asking for the browser title no i need the page title (page name) is there any filter to do that ?

i want to change using PHP not from admin area

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want. Which HTML element do you want to change, and change it to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to dashboard -> appearance -> edit -> page.php 
that is the file you want to edit...

if you want to find it with FTP -> /wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/page.php
if you want many different page templates check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

also for editing style: 
/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/style.css

Comment: i want to change it using PHP my friend and i want to change the page title

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU - I edited my answer for you, did you try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If u mean Tagline, Then go to My Account > Edit my profile > settings

There u can change

Comment: i want to change the page title .. not the entire wordpress title and i want to do that using PHP thanks  alot

Answer (score 0):

- You can give the title to the page in `<title>` tag of header.php in case of template 
    pages.

[or]

- You can change the page title in admin dashboard -> Pages -> change the label named 
    Title.